# Difficulties adding data to R dataset

Tags: r

I'm not too advanced with R so any help would be appreciated. I am trying to add values to columns in my dataset and my dataset is called 'katie'.
For example, in the column 'word' I'd like to select instances where 'SUBJECTED' is written and then post 'middle' in the column 'pre.environment', on the same line as 'SUBJECTED' is written. Is there something that I am doing wrong? With this code, the initial line definitely works (as I can see how many "SUBJECTED" items are recognized in the column 'word') but nothing happens when I enter the second line of code.

```
>x=grep("SUBJECTED", katie$word)
>katie[x,]$pre.environment= c('middle')
```

I hope this example is sufficient. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I tried your example, it should work. it doesn't print, did you look at `katie`, katie? for example, `x=grep("4", mtcars$gear); mtcars[x,]$mpg= c('middle'); mtcars`

Comment: The above code works fine for me. I agree with @rawr

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code, if I understand your question correctly,

```
katie$pre.environment <- ifelse(grepl("SUBJECTED", katie$word),
                                yes = "middle",
                                no  = katie$pre.environment)
```